# Importing multiple SQL tables using pandas

Tags: python, sql, database, pandas

I have a database that contains multiple tables, and I am trying to import each table as a pandas dataframe. I can do this for a single table as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import pypyodbc

conn = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};\
                        SERVER=serveraddress;\
                        UID=uid;\
                        PWD=pwd;\
                        DATABASE=db")

df1 = psql.read_frame('SELECT * FROM dbo.table1', conn)
```

The number of tables in the database will change, and at any time I would like to be able to import each table into its own dataframe. How can I get all of these tables into pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your SQL server, you can inspect the tables in a database.

For example:

```
tables_df = pd.read_sql('SELECT table_name FROM database_name', conn)
```

Now your table names are accessible as a pandas data frame, you just need to parse it out:

```
table_name_list = tables_df.table_name

select_template = 'SELECT * FROM {table_name}'
frames_dict = {}
for tname in table_name_list:
    query = select_template.format(table_name = tname)
    frames_dict[tname] = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

Your dictionary `frames_dict` contains all the dataframes with the table_name as the key