# Importing all the sql tables into python using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have an requirement wherein I would like to import all the tables stored in the sql database into python. I have successfully created a python code for it as follows:

`import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
from pandas import DataFrame
db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="********")
pointer = db.cursor()
pointer.execute("use stock")
pointer.execute("SELECT * FROM 3iinfotech")
data = pointer.fetchall()
data = DataFrame(data,columns =['date','open','high','low','close','volume'])`

Using this I am able to successfully import the Tables data into a pandas Dataframe.

But as can be seen from the database schema there are multiple tables which will again increase in the future.

[Full database schema along with output of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHnif.png)

The dataframe looks like:

[Imported table from sql converted to DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM1gn.png)

Is there any ways using loops or by any other methods that this script can be automated for all the tables in a given database.

I referred the following :

[Importing multiple SQL tables using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912373/importing-multiple-sql-tables-using-pandas)

But this does not work in my case.

Thanks.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL error come from ' around the table name, It's not the best but if you are working on a local application, you can workaround with the f strings:

```
with connection.cursor() as pointer:
    pointer.execute("use use stock")
    pointer.execute("SHOW TABLES")

    tables_tuples=[]
    for table_dict in pointer:
        for k,v in table_dict.items():
            tables_tuples.append(v)


for tables_name in tables_tuples:
    with connection.cursor() as pointer:
    
        #pointer.execute(f"SELECT * FROM %s",tables_name)
        pointer.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {tables_name}")
        
        connection.commit()


        df=pd.DataFrame(pointer)
        print(df)
```

Comment: The statement:    pointer.execute("SELECT * FROM %s", table)
Shows an error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''3iinfotech'' at line 1"